# English translation of "Lemme des bouts"

Tags: traduction, anglais, mathématiques

I am student in mathematics writing my master thesis and at some point I use the [*"Lemme des bouts"*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemme_des_bouts) or *"Lemme de sortie de tous compacts"* in ODE's theory. As I am writing it in English, I am looking for the translation of the name of this lemma, I couldn't find anything on internet. Is there any French speaking mathematicians who could help me with this ?

Comment: Even if this question was on-topic, I'm not sure anyone here has the expertise on that subject. I think the best thing you can do is ask this question one of the Math SE forums, formulated like this: "What is the name of the lemma that goes somewhat like this : [*your rough translation of the lemma*]? I couldn't find a source for it in English." That's on-topic there, and you'll have a lot of English speakers with the math background you need.

Comment: Salut. Peut-être demander dans leur salle de chat. Peut-être que tu peux identifier un terme via des Q&A, par exemple à partir de [ceci](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112199/differential-equations-and-axiom-of-choice), voir les Q&A liées à droite. Aussi, as-tu regardé des pages plus générales de wikipédia sur le sujet qui parleraient de _solutions maximales d’une equation différentielle_. Je ne connais pas le sujet, mais au contexte on peut probablement identifier ça.

Comment: I wonder if what you're searching for in the context of ODE isn't the [Extreme Value Theorem](https://www.cuemath.com/calculus/extreme-value-theorem/)

Comment: @mins : Non, c'est pas ça. Il me semblait me souvenir que les anglophones l'appelaient "Cauchy-Lipschitz’s corollary theorem", mais je ne retrouve pas en googlant. Pour finir, t'as trouvé, Falcon ? Ça m'intéresse, du coup...